# Macro with parameter x and output $x and @x

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write an macro:

```
#define FCT( x ) fct( ($ ## x), (@ ## x).first_line, (@ ## x).first_column )
```

The output of the macro should look like in this example:

```
FCT(2) --> fct( $2, @2.first_line, @2.first_column )
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the `@` seems to lead to errors. Is this even possible with the **C** preprocessor?

At the moment I am using this macro:

```
#define FCT(x,y) fct( x, y.first_line, y.first_column )
FCT($2,@2) --> fct( $2, @2.first_line, @2.first_column )
```

That works and is short enough for me, but I asked me if the first macro is somehow possible.

Comment: Neither `$` nor `@` are legal tokens in normal C code so what do you need this for? It won’t produce legal code.

Comment: It would have been good if you had given the error message. I would suspect that @ will not paste to a valid preprocessing token, since it has no meaning within C++

Comment: Probably, you want to use GNU m4? It is a way more powerful macroprocessor.

Comment: I'm using flex/bison, there i have to use $1, @1, etc. I don't want to use another preprocessor. Yes, the error was something line "not a valid preprocessing token".

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Correct me, but it is fine if the macro expands to a string or something. It need not be a C code.

Comment: @Thrustmaster No, that’s wrong. The macro preprocessor can only handle valid preprocessor tokens (§2.5 in the C++ standard) which are subsequently converted to tokens (§2.7). Invalid tokens are an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, MSVC accepts `$` as a valid symbol for identifiers. As it was correctly stated above this should not be so according to the standard. The `@` is a preprocessor operator that should normally be applied to parameters of the macro. You cannot use it as part of an identifier. Is your output a C program?

Comment: I know and work with a C compiler for embedded systems that has decided to prefix `inline` and other keywords with `@` for some reason. This makes it impossible to remove them via a define.

Comment: @dinfehur, Just replace `$` and `@` with other prefixes, which are made of valid identifier characters (maybe `X_` and `Y_`).

Comment: I didn't choose the name, I'm using flex/bison. I have to write $1 for a token, and @1 for the position of the token.

Comment: I am not an expert in the syntax of Bison, AFAIK Bison source is not processed with the macroprocessor. Bison is generating C-code. Only after that C-compiler (and the macroprocessor) kicks in. My understanding is that you cannot use macroprocessing on the Bison level. P.S. I have my own LR generator, similar to Bison. In my system the grammar source is processed using full C-preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a general concatenation macro maybe:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_(a,b)
#define CONCAT_(a,b) a##b
#define FCT( x ) fct( CONCAT($,x), CONCAT(@,x).first_line, CONCAT(@,x).first_column )
```

Comment: Did you try it? It certainly won't trick the GNU C preprocessor into generating invalid tokens: http://ideone.com/TO8ow

Comment: also doesn't work, same error: `pasting "@" and "2" does not give a valid preprocessing token`. It seems this doesn't work with standard preprocessor.